# Make FINDSTR stop searching after a match is found

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

Is there a way to make the `FINDSTR` command in Windows Command Prompt/Batch files stop searching after it finds a match?

I have a large document repository where I am searching using:

```
SET /P SEARCHTERM=Enter ID number  _
FINDSTR /s /m /f:"%~dp0_Reports\MasterFilelist.txt" /c:%SEARCHTERM%
```

to search the documents for a specific UNIQUE string that will only appear in ONE of the documents. For the sake of saving time, I want `FINDSTR` to stop searching once it finds a match. Is this possible?

Comment: Not directly no. I'd expect that your alternative would be to perform a findstr against each file listed in the text file, and use a goto dependibg upon the errorlevel returned. My experience of the speed of findstr /s however is such that I'm a little dubious about any time saving improvements by doing so.

Comment: You will need a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) processing `MasterFileList.txt` and leave it in case of a match by [`goto`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html): `for /F "usebackq delims= eol=|" %%I in ("%~dp0_Reports\MasterFileList.txt") do findstr /M /C:"%SEARCHTERM%" "%%I" && goto :NEXT` (put label `:NEXT` in the following line). *N. B.:* a) the `/S` option is useless together with `/F`; b) the search string should be quoted like `/C:"%SEARCHTERM%"`…

Comment: As a side note, for your submitted code, I'd probably use ```%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /SLMIF:"%~dp0_Reports\MasterFilelist.txt" /C:"%SEARCHTERM%"```. The `/L` as extra protection from potential metacharacters being input, and case insensitivity, _(`/I`)_, as we've no idea if your ID Numbers could contain alphabetic characters. As we also have no idea what the content of the `.txt` file contains, I cannot be sure if the `/S` option is needed or otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the input Compo and aschipfl. I have two ```FOR /F IN DO (DIR /B > *.txt)``` loops to get to the ```MasterFilelist.txt``` document. As for the ID itself, it is strictly a numeric ID number, no characters or letters (I should probably restrict the search to numbers only) and the documents I am searching in are single column ```.CSV``` lists of ID numbers processed on a given day named ```20220707_<USER>.csv``` or whatever the day is and then the list.